# WeakReference equality

Tags: scala

How can I compare ref.WeakReference instance with another ref.WeakReference instance?

The built-in equals method fails trivial check:

```
import ref.WeakReference
val st : String = "qwerty"
val r1 : WeakReference[String] = new WeakReference(st)
val r2 : WeakReference[String] = new WeakReference(st)
r1 == r2
res1: Boolean = false
```

It's possible to use `r1.get == r2.get` but this method is unusable for comparing references to disposed objects: in both cases I'll get None and None equals for None

Is it possible to actually compare weakreference?

Comment: can't you look in the source code and see how == is implemented?

Comment: == is implemented in Any class and it calling equals(that : Any) method

Comment: and how is equals of WeakReference implemented...

Comment: `self equals other` - that is written in the source code for proxy class. All the magic are left behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is no safe default behaviour when the object has been dereferenced; consequently, WeakReference doesn't pretend to provide one. Wrapping it in an object that does implement the appropriate behaviour is trivial. If you like, you can even provide an implicit and let the type system ensure your reference is wrapped by the correct equals behaviour as required.

So the short answer is: This is not provided to protect you from not thinking about it.

EDIT (in response to comment):
You are building an identity service. This maintains a mapping of entity<->identifier which must persist for the lifetime of all references to the entity. Most of the time the entity and the object representing the entity are the same thing, for these occasions use a `WeakHashMap[Entity,Identifier]` for the entity->identifier mapping and a `WeakHashMap[Identifier,WeakReference[Entity]]` for the identifier->entity mapping (if and only if required).

If you really need the entity to live as long as references to its identifier, you can do this by maintaining a shadow identifier that can reincarnate the identifier when required, so using: `WeakHashMap[Entity,Shadow[Identifier]` and `WeakHashMap[Identifier, Tuple2[Shadow[Identifier],Entity]]` wrapped with appropriate reincarnation logic in Shadow watching the ReferenceQueues.

Most of the time however, if the simple approach is inadequate, you have a need to track externalised identifiers, at that point things are both extremely tricky and extremely sensitive to the exact problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'm wrapping WeakReference in my custom class, writing equals for it and therefore asking stackoverflow how should I write this custom methods. I'm using get method temporary and looking for a better solution for now.

Comment: WeakReference is safe enough with it Option[T] result for get method. If it was C++ weakreference would store an actual address and its state (active,dereferenced) and this pair may be matched.

Comment: You have to call `get()`. It is here that the object manages atomically obtaining a strong-reference to the object (there is always a potential race with the gc). Don't try to bypass `get()`, just call it, check for `None`, and process accordingly.

Comment: As I've written in the starting post calling `get` have a drawback: this method is not helpful for expired weakreferences.

Comment: Ok, if that is your concern you are going to have to let us know what you are trying to achieve with a weak reference that can retain equality of identity after the expiry of the referenced object. There are ways of achieving such a thing, but a) you probably don't want this, b) they include trade-offs that are sensitive to the wider context of the problem.  So what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: creating an unique identifier from a object wihout tying this object to a garbage collector. It may be achieved by adding an object to a collection and storing associated key. But weakReference seemed at first glance more natural in this role.

Comment: You can't in fact do what you desire without a WeakReference; however, for what you want, you are better off letting WeakHashMap manage the WeakReferences on your behalf, no point in reinventing the wheel.